# .htaccess rewrite multiple value rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I want this url:
restaurant.mealhub.nl/menu/?restaurant_name=chinese-haren

to rewrite to this url:
http://restaurant.mealhub.nl/chinese-haren/menu

this is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$2/$ /$2/?restaurant_id=$1 [L]
```

What am i doing wrong? And what is best practice for this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $2/?restaurant_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```